# Is it possible to access linux/ramdisk code memory from its running system?

Tags: linux, embedded, flash-memory, integrity, source-code

I'm working with an embedded Linux device that has to be auditioned by a regulatory agency.

The agency will select a few devices in the field to check if the code running is the same as auditioned.

In oder to do so, the user who is checking the device selects a few read-only memory areas (where our application is) of the flash memory and our application has to output its hash md5 sum.

If the hash matches the hash of the device that was auditioned, all good.

The problem is: How can I ensure integrity of the operating system code as well?

Is there any flag/mechanism I can compile my Linux with so I'll have access to ROM memory area of the zImage from which it was copied to RAM? And what about the ramdisk?

Comment: You can read the memory (possibly now it is a kernel configuration option, because of security abuse). But like programs, loader could change some addresses (depending on where exactly the kernel is placed).